# how to end input multiple lines in console for c++?

Tags: c++, console

In code like the following:

```
while(getline(cin, line))
{
    // do something
}
```

How can I tell the console to stop accepting input?

[This](https://repl.it/repls/GreatSimultaneousSemicolon) is a link to the full code.

Comment: Add a condition in your while loop, when to stop.

Comment: You could do the same thing that a c-style string does: terminate with a canary value, a value that cannot possibly exist in valid input. You test all inputs for the canary value. If the input is not the canary, you add it to the array. If it is the canary, you exit the loop. Don't forget that you also need to stop when the array is full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hitting ctrl+D on Unix-like systems (including Linux), or ctrl+Z on Windows is the standard way to signal "End of input" to command-line programs (traditionally called "EOF" for "end of file"). It will cause `std::getline` to return a value that will evaluate as `false` in your while statement, ending the loop and continuing with the rest of your program.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a condition like `line == "end"` and break out of the while loop if that happens, but if you want to avoid changing the code, Ctrl+D will send an EOF and will tell the terminal to stop accepting inputs.

Comment: "and will tell the terminal to stop accepting inputs." Not exactly. The terminal will happily keep accepting inputs. What it actually does is sets some eof bits, but you can just clear them and keep reading. (On Linux you can use `std::cin.clear()`, on macOS you need to use `std::cin.clear()` and also `std::clearerr(stdin)`).